# How to get /64 as prefix length when using DHCPv6 and radvd?

Tags: virtual-machines, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04, dhcpv6, radvd

For our networking course we were asked to set up a DHCPv6 server in a virtual machine.
I choose to work on a virtual machine(on VMware) running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 and Lubuntu 14.04 as test client with network adapters set for a specific LAN. I started by configuring isc-dhcp-server to function for IPv6 as described in this [post](http://blog.netpro.be/dhcpv6-configuration-isc-dhcp-server/) and I ended up with a functioning dhcpv6 with a configuration file( /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf) containing this lines:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 100;
max-lease-time 200;
subnet6 2001:4340:4532:0400::/64{
   range6  2001:4340:4532:0400::0004 2001:4340:4532:0400::0006;
}
```

I also made the necessary changes to the init script to set the .conf, the .pid, the lease file and configured the interface ens33 with a static address as shown here : [static ip set through gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojFTb.png)

**The problem is that the client is receiving a /128 address.**

After some research I found-out that the DHCPv6 server doesn't give information about prefix length and that it must be broadcasted using Router Advertisements. So, I installed radvd on the same VM, enabled forwarding, disabled ufw and configured it with this config file :

```
interface ens33{
#this is important :
AdvSendAdvert on;
MaxRtrAdvInterval 6;
MinRtrAdvInterval 4;
#this is important to :
AdvManagedFlag on;
AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
prefix 2001:4340:4532:400::/64
{

  AdvOnLink on;
  AdvAutonomous off;
};
```

And I get this on the client side :
[ifconfig on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ZTO.png) 
I'm also using this as network settings on this client :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se8Fa.png).
When I enable the AdvAutonomous or change settings in the Editing wired connection window I do get a /64 address with the right prefix through SLAAC indicating that the RAs are received and doing there work but that is not what I'm looking for.

I've been stuck with this for quit some time and please keep in mind that I'm a new to networking and Linux so please forgive my lack of knowledge.